# What is sequenceName in @SequenceGenerator annotation and how does it work?

Tags: hibernate

Here is the quote from another stackoverflow answer:

> sequenceName is the name of the sequence in the DB. This is how you
> specify a sequence that already exists in the DB

I don't quite understand what "specify a sequence that already exists in the DB" is, so have a few questions:

1. I am creating a new sequence how can it already exist in DB?
2. Is this just a name how the sequence is saved in DB?
3. What does Hibernate use if sequenceName is not specified?

P.S. I do understand how dumb the questions are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are only creating a new sequence if you are using Hibernate to create your schema. That is controlled by the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property or the `javax.persistence.schema-generation` family of properties.
2. Yes
3. It falls back to a default naming convention for the sequence.

If your table automatically generates the id, then you don't need to define the sequences directly. You can just use the annotation `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. This not only reduces your code complexity, but also now each insert will take one query instead of two.